"The fat, sunny ring of the world's casually afternooned" in Stanley Elkin's "I Look Out for Ed Wolfe"
"I Look Out for Ed Wolfe" by Stanley Elkin, published in Esquire magazine (1st September, 1962), contains in its second paragraph the sentence:

In the sound of his own voice he detected the accent of the night school and the correspondence course, and nothing of the fat, sunny ring of the world's casually afternooned.


Does "world's" refers to "world's -i.e. everybody's- accent"?
How should one interpret "afternooned"? Something like "relaxed, loose..."?


The adjective “afternooned” comes from a verb “to afternoon”, which, although it is not recorded in dictionaries, means “to spend the afternoon”, as in this passage from a 1984 fantasy novel:

Dana nooned and afternooned with Charley Oceaan and his friends. It was pleasant to be back with the real bucks, with the strong and earth-growing men. He late-afternooned with Elaine Kingsberry and with Celeste the belle, with whom Elaine was staying.
R. A. Lafferty (1984). Half a Sky. Hachette.

So, in Elkin, the “casually afternooned” are people who spend their afternoons in a casual manner, because they are independently wealthy and do not have to spend their afternoons working. Elkin’s narrator contrasts these people with the protagonist, who works for a living, and so if he studies it has to be at a night school or via a correspondence course.
The addition of “world’s” may be to emphasize that such people—the independently wealthy—occur all over the world.

First, I thank and do appreciate your editing and making the text of my question clearer and more readable .

Second, as it seems that "to afternoon" is an intrasitive verb, I am wondering if "afternooned" could be referring to "those who pass afternoon...". Can we designate those who painfully walked as "the painfully walked"?
Perhaps if there existed a transitive meaning of the verb (for example "to afternoon sth: make take a relaxed posture...") then "the afternooned" would refer to all those who...
I'm trying to formulate and figure out the structure with the pure mechanical liguistic logic of a non-native, as you might have guessed
